# newline question

Tags: php

I want to detect a carriage return or a newline character when a user enters data into a textarea. What is the best way to handle this? I've tried str_replace with escape characters but carriage returns and newlines are not detected.

---

OK, say I type the following into a textarea:

```
The summer was hot this year
but next year is supposed to be cooler.
```

I want to detect the CRs. In this case, there is one.

Comment: Can you paste your code where you tried `str_replace`?

Comment: Define "detect". What does `str_replace` have to do with detection? It replaces things.

Comment: **you should post the code you've tried.** most likely it's not the method you want, but to correct mistakes in your implementation.

Comment: What do you want the end result of the operation to be?  Do you want all carriage returns and newlines to be gone, do you want to replace carriage returns followed by newlines to just newlines?  It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 5):

Newlines could be \r, \r\n, or \n, depending on the client.

```
$input = preg_replace('/\r\n?/',"\n",$input)
```

will standardize all of your newlines to "\n" regardless of where they came from.

Comment: that's what I meant to post actually

Comment: Well nowadays probably not \r but in the past Mac before OSX used a carriage return if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Mac OS up to version 9 used a single `\r` for newline.

Comment: the question is not about the os. it's about textarea filled in the browser.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that `$input` comes from the client, and we want to find the newlines.  The form of the newlines depends on the OS of the client.  We don't care what the OS is, but we do care where the newlines are.

Comment: nope, it's not. the problem with your answer is you NERVER used the code you wrote here. it's just off your head, not real life.

Comment: @Col I've read a lot of your comments, and you're spot on most of the time.  As for newlines in textareas, however, that's something you should research a bit.  I have.

Comment: you fail to follow your own logic. even if linebreaks would be OS-specific, your code will fail on the unix-way alone \n. go research

Comment: @Col My code converts non-\n linebreaks to \n.  Unix linebreaks are already \n.  What's the point of converting \n to \n?

Comment: oh, I've overlooked that your replacement is \n. all others made it an empty string, so, I was blind in a way thinking you're doing the same. then your code would work well, my apologies.

Comment: I think the problem here is not how to replace it but to understand what the poster of the question exactly means with detect a carriage return or a newline character?  Does an \r or \r\n need to be replaced with \n?  Do they all need to be removed?  Does he want to know the position of the those or does he needs to know whether it's a \r\n or \n ?  It's not clear from the question what the result has to be.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this with str_replace:

```
function replace_newline($string) {
  return (string)str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '', $string);
}
```

Comment: Hey Vince, I already found that thread but it doesn't work. Let me post an example above.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. It's always worked a charm for me.

You need to replace \n AND \r, it's because a linux system and a windows system use different characters for newlines.

```
$input = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'',$input);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways how new line is stored.
Some systems use only `"\n"` some `"\r"` and some both `"\r\n"`. You need to check for both `"\r"` and `"\n"`

Comment: Thanks Michael. I've tried both ways and neither one was detected.

Comment: Michael, if I test with both escape chars using str_replace and it doesn't work, is there something else I can do?

Comment: There needs to be at least `\r` or `\n`. Unless it is somehow automatically parsed and it contains only `<br />` or `<br>` Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Or check for chr(10) and replace on that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `preg_replace` because that can be used for regex replacements and then you can replace using `\n` or `\r` or any combination you require although I believe str_replace should also work fine.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong here, nothing has worked. If I have a paragraph that is broken down into say, 4 lines, I need to detect the 3 CRs

Comment: Can you post your code, probably it's something else that's wrong in your code as the posted examples should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function replace_newlines($string) {
    return preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n/', '', $string);
}
```